# Running Electrical Wires exterior to interior

Tags: electrical, wiring, code-compliance, outdoor, conduit

I need a new line placed in a certain area of my house, (*for a fish tank*) but running it inside isn't a super realistic option, as it's a good distance and the joists run perpendicular to where I would need to run the wire. So I am planning on running it outside around the house.

The total distance is  60-100 ft depending on which direction I run it, but I am a little confused on how i should do it.

Do I need to use conduit if I am running outdoor grade wire (*not sure how to really waterproof the run inside from the outside wall without conduit either*)?

If I do use conduit then is it okay to use NM or THHN in it, or do I need to still run outdoor grade wire? **Also** is Schedule 40 conduit suitable, or does it have to be EMT?

I am having a hard time finding some of the answers to this in the code. Burying it isn't an option, as there's too much concrete and pipes/electrical in the way.

Comment: You can usually drill joists and run cable through them, running cable outside to avoid going through joists sounds like significant overkill, but ill allow the licenced electricians to post formal answers. That being said, you can get coated armoured cable rather than conduit for exterior, but conduit is probably best outdoors for most applications.You dont want to run romex in conduit because you need way higher diameter conduit to make it work. They make THHN wire specifically to run in conduit

Comment: The problem with the joists is the drilling in a two story house on the first floor. If they ran parallel i could cutout small patches of drywall and thread the wires through. If I have to drill through a joist every 14 inches then i basically have to cut out all the dry wall on the way to where I am going which would be like 50 feet which seems like substantially more work (not to mention i can never seem to match the texture on my ceiling which would probably lead me to replace the entire ceiling). I appreciate the rest of the info!!! Do you think schd40 is fine as conduit?